# Fetching data from database into text boxes

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have designed a SQL Server database app in which I fetch data from database and then insert in text boxes. I use a function to fetch data in data table from database and then I populate textboxes. I have to use this coding again and again:

```vb
If Dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    
    TxtCust_Id.Text = Dt.Rows(0).Item(0)
    TxtCust_City.Text = Dt.Rows(0).Item(1)
    TxtCust_Area.Text = Dt.Rows(0).Item(2)
    
Else
    
    TxtCust_Id.Text = String.Empty
    TxtCust_City.Text = String.Empty
    TxtCust_Area.Text = String.Empty
End if
```

Text boxes names changes according to query tables. My question is. Is it possible to make a function or procedure to populate data in text boxes from datatable using loops or any other method?  Thanks in advance.

```vb
Shared Function ExecuteSelectDt(ByVal SelectCommand As String) As DataTable
    
    Cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Sda = New SqlDataAdapter
    ' Dt = New DataTable

    Try
        DBConnection()    ' Database connection details
    
        Sda = New SqlDataAdapter(SelectCommand, Con)
        Dim dt2 As New DataTable
        Sda.Fill(dt2)
        CloseConnection()
        Return dt2
    Catch ex As Exception
        CloseConnection()
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return dt
    End Try
End Function
    
Private Sub TxtCust_Name_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TxtCust_Name.Leave
    
    SQuery = "select Cust_Id, Cust_City, Cust_Area from TBLCustommers where Cust_Name= '" & TxtCust_Name.Text & "'"
    
    Dt = Nothing
    Dt = BM_Class_Liberary.SQLSereverDB.ExecuteSelectDt(SQuery)
    
    If Dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    
        TxtCust_Id.Text = Dt.Rows(0).Item(0)
        TxtCust_City.Text = Dt.Rows(0).Item(1)
        TxtCust_Area.Text = Dt.Rows(0).Item(2)
    
    Else
    
        TxtCust_Id.Text = String.Empty
        TxtCust_City.Text = String.Empty
        TxtCust_Area.Text = String.Empty
    End if 
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Use data binding. You will avoid a ton of code.

Comment: Brother please explain i want to learn from you.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hulrJWg3rEo

Comment: Search DataBinding tutorial in Google. For Windows Forms it's the way to go. I also advise you to use the DataSet designer and create all your queries in the designer. Typed DataAdapters will automatically be created for you. Same goes for DataTables and DataRows.

Comment: Thanks very much i ignored data binding. But now i will read and focus on data binding.

Answer (score 1):

```vb
'create and populate list
dim txtBoxes as new List(of TextBox)();
for each ctrl as Control in Form.Controls
    if ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(TextBox) then txtBoxes.Add(ctrl)
next

' then do this when you get DataTable
dim theRow as DataRow = dt.Rows(0); ' whatever logic you have to getting needed row
for each col as DataColumn in dt.Columns
    ' use system.linq
    txtBoxes.First(function(tb) tb.Name = col.ColumnName).Text = theRow(col.ColumnName).ToString() 
next
```

Note, when `theRow(col.ColumnName)` is `DBNull.Value`, `ToString` will return `string.Empty`, which is fine because `.Text` can't have `Nothing`

Also, I used `First` because I did it with the premise that each column has text box.

Or, using the dictionary. Even better, I think

```vb
'create and populate dictionary
dim txtBoxes as new Dictionary(of string, TextBox)();
for each ctrl as Control in Form.Controls
    if ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(TextBox) then txtBoxes.Add(ctrl.Name, ctrl)
next

' then do this when you get DataTable
dim theRow as DataRow = dt.Rows(0); ' whatever logic you have to getting needed row
for each col as DataColumn in dt.Columns
    
    txtBoxes(col.ColumnName).Text = theRow(col.ColumnName).ToString() 
next
```